# Where to declare certain Qt objects for the QMainWindow: in header file or in constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, declaration, header-files

There are several objects in my main window (QMenus, QLabels, QLayouts, the central widget, etc.) that I am realizing don't need to be declared in the main window's header file. Instead, it is fine to declare them in the main window's constructor.

E.g., before:

in mainwindow.h

```
private:
    QMenu *fileMenu;
    // etc.
```

in mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("File");
    // etc.
}
```

vs.

in mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    QMenu *fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("File");
    // etc.
}
```

If scope isn't an issue (e.g., I don't need access to fileMenu anywhere other than when I create it in mainwindow's constructor), does it matter where I declare it? Is there a "best practice" for such situations?

I'm relatively new to Qt/C++, and I realize this might be more of a C++ question than a Qt question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common rule to use smallest scope possible for every variable you declare.

So, you'd better do not make them class members (not declare them in header file).